# Python как получить свойства объекта генерируемые автоматически?

Tags: python, объекты

У меня есть объект `data` у которого есть поля: `link_1`, `name_link_1`, `link_2`, `name_link_2` и так далее

Как я могу получить их всех через цикл?

**Пытался:**

```
array_links = []
for i in range(0,5):
  #array_local = [data.globals()['name_link_' + i], data.globals()['link_' + i]]
  array_local = [data.eval('name_link_' + i),data.eval('link_' + i)]
```

Comment: `print(dir(data))` для начала попробуйте

Comment: @insolor верное замечание, но этот список берётся со стороннего API, косяк на их стороне. Мне же надо сделать(

Comment: @CrazyElf я выведу объект и увижу эти поля, для чего?

Comment: @artemgh Ну в принципе вы можете проитерироваться по этому списку `dir(data)`. Просто нужно посмотреть есть ли там эти поля и много ли там лишнего.

Comment: data.__dict__ не выведет то, что вам надо? на выходе будет {атрибут : значение}

Comment: @CrazyElf я знаю, что они есть.

Comment: Зачем пять раз переписывать одну переменную (в цикле)?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не переживайте, просто код вырезан из контекста, дальше я добавляю его в глобальный список

Comment: @artemgh, `список берётся со стороннего API` - ясно, тогда вопрос снимается)

Answer (score 2):

Большое спасибо @Dmitry я сделал это следующим образом:

```
array_links = []
for i in range(0,5):
  array_local = [data.__dict__['name_link_' + str(i)] ,data.__dict__['link_' + str(i) ] ]
```

Comment: на здоровье. [Ссылка на описание](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) в доке

Comment: В данном случае лучше `getattr` чем `__dict__`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если знать атрибут то да, а если нужен поиск по названию атрибута, то нет

Comment: @Dmitry, getattr по названию атрибута получает его значение. `getattr(data, 'name_link_' + str(i))` будет аналогично `data.__dict__['name_link_' + str(i)]`

Comment: @insolor полностью согласен, просто в моей голове я собрал так, что названия атрибутов не известны явно и через словарь можно было по совпадению `link` отлавливать. А в реализии ТС они хардкодятся. Ну, ок =)